# c++ and mysql trying to create batch processing with addBatch()

Tags: c++, mysql, batch-file, prepared-statement

I have a c++ program on a [g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2] debian OS working.

I am using the "libmysqlcppconn-dev" and do my compiling with the following command:

```
g++ -Wall xxx.cpp -o xxx -lmysqlcppconn
```

My part of code is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
...
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet *res;
sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

int main(){
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "xxx", "xxx");
    con->setSchema("xxx");


    pstmt = con->prepareStatement("update test set `data1`=?, `data2`=? where `data3`=?");
    pstmt->setInt(1, 1);
    pstmt->setString(2, "asdf");
    pstmt->setString(2, "qwer");
    pstmt->addBatch();
    return true;
}
```

The compiler complains about that addBatch() is not a known function in pstmt.
My goal is to use more updates and collect them as jobs.

Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It simply isn't there. Not all available in the JDBC API is available in the C++ interface. `con->getMetaData()->supportsBatchUpdates()` exists though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added your code-line before the preparestatement and got the following error:

/usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:43:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class sql::DatabaseMetaData’

How can I achieve your advice?

Comment: `#include <cppconn/metadata.h>`

Comment: Thanks again. Now I get:
xxx.cpp:341:10: error: ‘class sql::PreparedStatement’ has no member named ‘addBatch’ :-(

Comment: Any further hint? :-)

Comment: Not really -- only the question if batch updates are really necessary. You may simulate them in most of the cases by repeatedly calling `pstmt->setXYZ();pstmt->execute();` may be enclosing the whole thing into an `start transaction`and `end transaction`.